# Calculate hash of document in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to calculate a hash of a document (using sha256) in SharePoint Online.

How can I do that? Can I use only JavaScript?

Do I need to do it using Add-In?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JS.

You need to get SharePoint online file firstly. How to get online file via [JSOM](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37575.sharepoint-online-working-with-files-inside-document-library-using-jsom.aspx).

Then you can calculate the SHA-256 of the file you get via [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060248/calculate-sha-256-hash-and-b64-of-a-file-in-javascript).